# jHipster: Karma tests pass with 'yarn test' but fail in WebStorm

Tags: angular, karma-runner, webstorm, jhipster, yarnpkg

I've set up a project using jHipster with an Angular 4 front end and I'm having issues running the Karma unit tests within my WebStorm (v2017.2.4) IDE.

However, if I run them all together using `yarn test` in the command line they all pass. This is really slowing me down because running all the tests like this is very time consuming when I only want to run a specific test quickly in the IDE.

The failure message in WebStorm I am getting is:

> Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for XXXService: (?).

(Where XXX is the name of one of the many services that fails).

I've set an empty jHipster generated project on github to demonstrate a project where I am encountering this problem: https://github.com/TLDC/jhi-karma-issue-test. Running any tests under src/test/javascript gives me this issue.

Is there a way to configure WebStorm to make these tests pass in the IDE and not just using yarn test?

**EDIT:** Discovered `yarn test` actually runs the command `yarn run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js`

**EDIT 2: I've found now in the Karma Server tab on WebStorm that it is reporting that webpack failed to compile before the tests run with a large number of various errors reported. I've included a snippet of this here:**

> > ERROR in [at-loader] ./spec/helpers/mock-principal.service.ts:14:59 
> >         TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
> >
> > ERROR in [at-loader] ./spec/test.module.ts:24:14 
> >         TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the
> >     'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

Full error report is here (up to truncation) https://gist.github.com/TLDC/af7d319d1c2a87bc1cfb9233e725bd3a

Comment: is there a github project representing a problem? Your question cannot be answered without having a reproducible example of your problem. No plunkr or whatsoever but  **a fully configured github project**

Comment: Im trying to make a small project that has the issue now. I can't share the actual code because its confidential. I'm having trouble making it not work in a small example though which is odd. The code we use in auto generated by jHipster so I'll add that tag to my question

Comment: Ok I generated an empty jhipster project and made a github for it: https://github.com/TLDC/jhi-karma-issue-test you can try run any Karma tests under src/test/javascript and they should fail in WebStorm with same error I was having

Comment: works totally fine for me. Webstorm 2017.2.3 . Which version do you have? What I did: right click on the .spec file, `run blabla.spec.ts`, `Test run` tool pops up, all tests are passed and then I can select a single file from the list to run again

Comment: I also have 2017.2.3. Why on earth doesn't it work on mine. That is exactly what I did too..

Comment: maybe what I did differently: I installed everything with `npm install`, not with `yarn`; using npm@5. Ideally this should not make any difference, but who knows...

Comment: I tried with npm install instead and it's still not working for me. You don't have any plugins for webstorm that may be doing something? Clutching at straws a bit here but I am very confused.

Comment: @smnbbrv or perhaps some settings you have? Could you possibly export your WebStorm setting and share them with me somehow?

Comment: nope, raw webstorm with just no settings... :(

Comment: I am so confused. I just did a fresh install on another machine pulled it down from github and it still doesn't work for me. I must be missing something

Comment: just got another idea. Did you try to make it on a really fresh machine? Maybe you have some global instance of karma / phantomjs / whatsoever installed with `npm i -g`? I don't have any. And what OS do you use?

Comment: The second time I tried it was on a super fresh machine. Never done any dev work on it before at all. Was Windows 8. First time was on Windows 10.

Comment: mine is macOS Sierra, maybe that's the point

Comment: That could be it. I wonder what's different. I've just noticed now in the Karma Server tab on WebStorm Im getting 'webpack: Failed to compile.' before Karma starts I guess this isnt happening for you?

Comment: Finally solved it, thanks for your help @smnbbrv. Since I cant award you the bounty I will try repay you in other ways. :)

Comment: that's really good that you found it :) looked like a really difficult one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to fix this issue.

Firstly, thanks to @smnbbrv it seems like this issue may only happen on Windows.
This makes some sense since it seems to be an issue with paths somewhere.

The problem I found was that before the Karma tests were running webpack was trying to compile the TypeScript files referencing a tsconfig.json file under:

> project-root/src/test/javascript/tsconfig.json

However, this file does not exist in this location and instead of reporting this as the issue it instead reported a large number of TypeScript compilation errors on the Karma Server console. This then causes the tests to fail.

I was able to fix this by simply copying the tsconfig.json file from its actual location at

> project-root/tsconfig.json

to the one expected by webpack in the Karma test runner. This then causes all tests to pass in WebStorm as expected.

Ideally it would be good to find some configuration to change somewhere to tell webpack where to look for this file but I cannot for the life of me find where to do this. But this workaround certainly works for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyTestModule` doesn't export `HttpModule` (hopefully it doesnt'), then test is not configured enough.
Just add `HttpModule` to `imports` and it should work in any enviropment:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [MyTestModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [AlertTableComponent],
  providers: [AlertService]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not so much looking for a code change solution since I know the tests work. They just don't work in the IDE. Also tried this out and they still don't work in the IDE.

Comment: Yes, they work. But you know, it's incorrect test bed configuration

Comment: Your fix also doesnt work. I've edited the original question a lot to clarify things a bit more.

Comment: your repo worked just fine, can you share your karma job config and errors if any?

Comment: sorry for slow reply I've attached a picture of my Karma config and a more verbose error

Comment: also what OS do you use?

Comment: I finally solved it. Thanks for your efforts ill award you the bounty for that.

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)